# Index scan is not working on json data set in postgres

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sql-tuning, postgresql-json

I'm trying to understanding of extracting data from `JSON` files in `PostgreSQL` with certain filter conditions.

Here is my query,

created index like below,

```
CREATE INDEX idx_startTimeL_n
    ON mytable USING btree
    (((data -> 'info'::text) ->> 'startTimeL'::text) )
```

If I run the explain select query

```
EXPLAIN   SELECT * FROM mytable
      WHERE (((data -> 'info'::text) ->> 'startTimeL'::text)::double precision) <= (date_part('epoch'::text, now()) * 1000::double precision)
      AND ((data -> 'info'::text) ->> 'startTimeL'::text)::double precision) >= (date_part('epoch'::text, now()) * 1000::double precision - 3600000::double precision)
     LIMIT 400000;
```

Query planner results are,

```
"Limit  (cost=0.00..36371.90 rows=220700 width=1568)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..36371.90 rows=220700 width=1568)"
"        Filter: (((((data -> 'info'::text) ->> 'startTimeL'::text))::double precision <= (date_part('epoch'::text, now()) * '1000'::double precision)) AND ((((data -> 'info'::text) ->> 'startTimeL'::text))::double precision >= ((date_part('epoch'::text, now()) * '1000'::double precision) - '3600000'::double precision)))"
```

So, here my question is why the `seq scan` happening instead of `index scan` even though table indexed with filter condition?

Comment: Because your index expression is different to the expression used in the WHERE clause

Comment: Is it possible to create an index with the same given expression in where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example query has a syntax error, unbalanced paranetheses.

If you want to look up into an index with double precision, then that is how the index must be defined.

```
CREATE INDEX ON mytable USING btree
    (((data -> 'info' ->> 'startTimeL')::double precision))
```